# Frequency division multiplexing FM Radio stations

Tags: receiver, fm, transmission

Can someone help me with this I'm confused on what it is supposed to look like?
[image]

Comment: What's the source of your confusion?  The problem seems very clear.  This is an example of band management.  They tell you how wide each channel is and how much spacing there is between those channels.

Comment: That doesn't even look specific to multiplexing.  It's just how you space out signals so they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: How do I calculate the channel spacing and what is the graph suppose to look like?

Comment: Do I draw from the 96.3 or 96.5?

Comment: Hi Dan, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @duston, yeah you're right... but I think easy to see how this could be a foundational setup for examining FDMA, "so now think of these discrete stations as sub channels in one big FM channel and now you..." etc etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site and welcome to radio!

A 150kHz channel that is "Centered at 96.5 MHz" means that channel will have 150kHz / 2 = 75kHz below 96.5 AND 75kHz above 96.5 MHz.

50kHz guard band between means that there will be at least 50kHz of space between the top-end of one channel and the bottom-end of the next channel so that they don't interfere.

```
96.3           96.5            96.7
|--------|-------|-------|-------|
            (75k | 75k)
            (  150k   )
```

Looks like may be for a class, happy learning!